# Can't access this.context inside a defined class and dataSources apollo-server-express

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, apollo-server, graphql-js

So my issue is trying to access the context inside this class. It always returns undefined. Now I tried working on this without the use of `dataSources` and everything works fine but once I introduce the `dataSources` inside `apolloServer`  constructor, I can't access the context.

**Here's my `apolloServer` constructor**

This is where is define the `apolloServer` constructor

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
 typeDefs,
 resolvers,
 dataSources: () => {
    return { 
        usersApi: new UsersApi()
     }
 },
 context:async({req,connection})=>{
 
 if(connection){
     return {
        connection.context;
     }
     
 }else{
 let user = req.user || "";
 
 if(user){
   let users = await Users.findOne({_id:req.user.id});
   return {users}  
 }}
   
 },

});
```

**Heres my Resolver to handle fetching user details after signup**

Here is one of my resolvers that resolves and fetches userdetails from the database

```
signUp:async(_,args,{ dataSources})=>{
       
         return dataSources.usersApi.addUsers(args);
}
```

**Here my class to handle this dataSource**

Here I define my class that executes the function to return `usersDetails` such as name and email once the user is loggedin.

```
class UsersApi{
 async getSignedUserDetails(){
        
        if(!this.context.users){
                throw new Error('Please signIn')
            }
            
        return await Users.find({_id:this.context.users.id});
    }
}
```

If I remove anything to do with the context in other functions within the class above, it works.
I've looked at a tone of resources but not been able to solve it yet. Appreciate any help.

Comment: check context in resolver ... `signUp:async(_,args,{ dataSources, users })=>{ console.log(users);` ... why 'users' when it is one user?

Comment: Users is just a preference in naming but will be sure to make it more understandable

Comment: So the users is being consoled as normal but how do I use it in the class. Because as I read in the documentation, the context should be present in the dataSources and viceversa.

Comment: yes, [by docs] it should ... console.log entire context? ... if this doesn't work you can pass user from resolver explicitely [with args, as usual]

Comment: So i tried console.log(context) and it returned [object Object] . Then I passed the users object directly to the resolvers and accessed it in the class and it worked. I don't like that method but right now I don't have an option. Thanks

Comment: it should be an object, try to list it's keys/properties

Comment: Also doesn't work, it might/might not be a bug